# Transform Latitude / Longitude position to X axis

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

My application is for race cars that run on the same circuit. I have the GPS data, latitude and longitude.
So far I can overlay the data (speed, acceleration, etc.) on an X/Y graph, with X being distance or time from a certain point. Imagine a point (the car) rotating several times in the same circle.
I separate each turn into laps and superimpose the laps of two cars, with the x axis by time or distance.

Now, I need to do that same superposition, but by latitude/longitude position.

For that I think I need to transform the lat/lon position to the x axis of the graph, but I'm not sure about that either.
The data is in two separate lists, one for each car.

Any way to do it?

Comment: Hi! This is unclear. What do you want on the $x$-axis? What do you want on the $y$-axis?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.